# Highlight Extension Flutter Widget Tree

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, tree, widget

I saw this video and all this trace line highlighting the widgets tree. I would like to add in my vscode, but after google search, I found nothing.

Any idea about the name of this extension, or maybe a configuration?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJAbM.png

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 9):

1. Make sure Dart is enabled
2. **open settings**. **(Ctrl + ,)**
3. **search settings** ->  **Dart: Preview Flutter Ui Guides**
4. Tick on **Dart:Preview Flutter Ui Guides**
5. Tick on **Dart: Preview Flutter Ui Guides Custom Tracking**

if it doesn't work, restart Visual Studio and check.

[image]